# What are the arguments of Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPasteSpecial].Show

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

VSTO excel's pasteSpecial dialog takes 30 args. I've tried looking everywhere but can not find what each argument stands for.

I am trying to set defaults for pasteSpecial when the dialogue pops up. (c# vsto2007)

```
bool isPaste = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPasteSpecial].Show
                (
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211087%28v=office.12%29.aspx) page, there are four arguments:

```
paste_num, operation_num, skip_blanks and transpose
```

So for example, this will show the dialog with Transpose checked:

```
bool isPaste = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPasteSpecial].Show
                    (Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, TRUE ...
```

I believe the other 26 arguments are placeholders, and that any dialog you chose would indicate 30 arguments.